# how to set data from component to the form dynamically using reactive form?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, dynamic, angular-reactive-forms

hello guys im new with angular and  im trying to Dynamically Creating Form Fields and set data to the form dynamically.
notice : ( the array inside the component,,, i now that my english bad hhhhhhh )

[Component :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm8cX.jpg)

[Form :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnyIx.jpg)

[Array :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryl5d.jpg)

thanks...

Comment: I see that you are new, please post your code as code blocks in the question itself: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

If you want those to be your initial values, instead of calling a new `inpliment` function, you could just assign the values on the creation phase.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  branch: this.fb.group({
    nom: ['automobile'],
    objectif: [''],
    realisation: [10],
    TC: ['0.2%']
  }),
  soulsbranch: this.fb.group({
    nom: ['Kerala'],
    objectif: [''],
    realisation: [20],
    TC: ['0.2%']
  })
})
```

Also, you shouldn't start your variables with caps like on `Field`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to set the array to the form. can you help me to do that????